# Qual a melhor maneira de gerar tabelas dinamicamente em php?

Tags: php

Tenho um admin e tenho sérias duvidas de como gerar tabelas em php normalmente o que faço é colar o html num editor web porém essa solução não me parece a melhor sugestões?

Comment: Ué, qual a dificuldade de escrever o código? Se quer digitar menos, pode usar o Emmet no seu editor de códigos favorito: https://emmet.io/

Comment: O problema é editar essas tabelas depois pois tem que refazer o html

Comment: Cara, detalha melhor a sua necessidade. No comentário ali embaixo você disse que as colunas mudam também, agora entendi o que você quis dizer: você quer passar um objeto e sair uma tabela formatada conforme os campos desse objeto, certo?

Comment: Isso exato gostaria de uma espécie de um template onde adicionasse uma linha com um campo texto algo assim e gerasse um campo na tabela queria saber a melhor forma de fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos que eu tenha várias tabelas no meu banco de dados, cada uma com uma estrutura diferente. Considerando que eu tenho dados(linhas) em todas elas, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php 
$dados; // essa variável tem um array com cada linha da tabela

// vou usar o primeiro resultado para conseguir a lista de colunas.
// Você pode querer alguma coisa mais robusta, tipo passar uma
// lista de campos e usar eles na view;
$colunas = array_keys($dados[0]);
?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <?php foreach ($colunas as $coluna): ?>
        <th><?= $coluna ?></th>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($dados as $linha): // para cada linha ?>
  <tr>
    <?php foreach ($linha as $key => $value): // para cada campo de cada linha ?>
      <td><?= $value ?></td>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Boa a resposta mas como eu faria para ter tds diferentes? Calcular os tds por exemplo se tivesse uma com 4 colunas e outra com 3?

Comment: Ué, são tabelas diferentes? Me dá um exemplo mais concreto na sua pergunta (edita ela). Se sua estrutura é mais complexa que isso, vai precisar tratar caso-a-caso, ou contar colunas a cada nova linha, mas aí vira um trabalho bem mais complexo, talvez seja melhor usar alguma coisa pronta, como uma datatable de jQuery: https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

Comment: Eu digo na mesma tabela se uma linha tiver 3 colunas e outra 4 para não quebrar a tabela. Mas realmente fica mais complexo.

Answer (score 0):

Essa função monta uma tabela a partir de qualquer select. $sql é a select desejada. Ex. de uso da função:

```
mostrarTabela("select cd, nome from tabela");
```

Espero que possa ser útil a alguém.

```
function mostrarTabela($sql){
//Mostra uma tabela com o resultado da select automaticamente
  global $banco; //conexao com o banco desejado feita fora da funcao. Se quiser pode colocar aqui.
  if (!$idSQLControle=mysql_query($sql,$banco))
   echo "<b>ERRO SQL:</b>" . $sql_Controle;
  $nrregSQLControle=mysql_num_rows($idSQLControle);      
  if ($nrregSQLControle > 0) {
    $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($idSQLControle);
    echo "<br><b>$sql_Controle</b><br/>";
    echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
    //cabecalho da tabela
    for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
    {
        $field = mysql_fetch_field($idSQLControle);
        echo "<td><b>{$field->name}</b></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    //dados da tabela
    while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($idSQLControle))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($linha as $colunas)
            echo "<td>$colunas</td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>";
  } else {
    echo "Registros não encontrados!";
  }
}
```